# How To Create A Link For "save Image As" To Download an Image In Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to make a link download like this

http://idwallpaper.com/download.php?image_id=1517

I have tried from other tutorial like this

```
<script>
function SaveFile(fname){
img.document.execCommand('saveas', null ,fname)
}
</script>


<iframe id="img" src="myimage.jpg" width="(image width + 20)px" height="(image height + 25)px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0px"></iframe>



<button onclick="SaveFile('myimage.jpg');">save as</button>
```

Does not work in FireFox though.....

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="myimage.jpg">Save As</a>
```

Plus a `Content-Disposition` header to set it as an attachment. You can adapt [this PDF example](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/06-08-2007/force-a-pdf-to-download) if you use Apache.